# Unable to establish relationship for two fact tables with multiple many-to-many dimensions in Excel Data Model

Tags: excel, model, pivot

I have 3 tables (FACT1, FACT2, DIM1, DIM2)

FACT1:

```
Code Month Value
058 1 500
059 1 600
061 1 700
058 2 1000
059 2 1000
061 2 1000
```

FACT2:

```
Service Month Status Value
058-buy 1 OK 700
059-purchase 1 Missing 800
061-trade 1 OK 900
058-buy 2 OK 300
059-purchase 2 Missing 400
061-trade 2 OK 500
```

DIM1:

```
Code Service
058 058-buy
059 059-purchase
061 061-trade
```

DIM2:

```
Month Name
1 January
2 February
3 March
```

I have all 4 tables loaded into Data Model in Excel and created a new measure in FACT1
Value Total:`=sum([Value])+sumx(FILTER('FACT2','FACT2'[Status]="OK"),'FACT2'[VALUE])`

I have also created relationship between tables:
FACT1(Code) to DIM1(Code)
FACT2(Service) to DIM1(Service)
FACT1(Month) to DIM2(Month)
FACT2(Month) to DIM2(Month)

However, when I insert a new pivot using the data model by having
Code from DIM1 on "ROW"
Month from FACT1 on "COLUMN"
New Measure Value Total on "Values"

I get something like this:

```
Code 1 2 Grand Total
058 1500 2000 2500
059 600 1000 1600
061 2100 2400 3100
Grand Total 4200 5400 7200
```

Somehow it will get sliced by Month properly, but if you pay attention to the last column of the pivot table `Grand Total`, they are correct! 2500 is indeed `500 + 700 + 1000 + 300`, 1600 is indeed `600 + 1000`, 3100 is indeed `700 + 900 + 1000 + 500`
The final grand total for the above 3 is correct at 7200 too.

Now the question is why the middle part of the pivot tables acts oddly?

Comment: Why are you using Month from `FACT1`, and not from `DIM2`? `FACT1` cannot filter `FACT2`, though `DIM2` can.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tested to filter either Fact with DIM2 and it's working great. Thanks for solving this issue, I always thought any object in FACT1 can be used as slicer once relationship established through a dimension table, now that you pointed this out totally changed my understanding already.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Have posted as an answer if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Pivot Table, use Month from the `DIM2` table, not the `FACT1` table. With your current set-up, `FACT1` cannot filter the `FACT2` table, though `DIM2` can.